# Use commandline to launch Chrome with POST data

Tags: javascript, forms, google-chrome, post

I have a script at the end of some test data that launches Chrome. Unfortunately I can't seem to find the switch to launch a url in POST or to include POST data.

I know you can possibly do `javascript:` in chrome's url bar to make it execute javascript, and then I could probably simulate a POST request, however when trying a test script, Chrome is just launching a blank page. I think it has something to do with the security feature. Is there a Chrome switch for disabling this security feature for that one webpage launch?

test script (found it here: https://productforums.google.com/d/msg/chrome/CLDQ5KhXfFk/x0r7PGY1CooJ, kind of nice)

```
javascript:W7=open('','A','width=320,height=240,resizable');W7.focus();with(W7.document){write('<title>Javascript Tester</title><center><form><textarea name=X rows=10 cols=34 wrap>javascript:</textarea><p><input type=button value=Run onclick=opener.location=X.value>');void(close())}
```

Comment: This is a bookmark right? I don't see any problems why this wouldn't work on the blank chrome page. Did you try using an xhr request on the Window popup?

Comment: Oops, sorry about not specifying. No, this is an external script using command line to run a web browser (chrome) on a windows system.

Comment: Is it necessary to uae chrome when using the commandline? Phantom.JS might be a better fit in this case. Anyways, you open this script by letting chrome open it AS an URL right? Have you tried running it as a `userscript`? I'm not sure why chrome wouldnt let you do a post request...

Comment: Chrome or IE 11, this will be on machines where people are not technical and may not have rights to download more software. Yes I did it with it opening it as a URL, however I need to specify some data, so much data it doesn't fit in a GET request. I will try userscript.

Comment: If not I guess a Browser Plugin would fit in as well, since it'll run even if users don't Start chrome with Command line. Maybe its possible for a system admin to add policies to chrome like: this Plugin cant be removed. This is possible in IE, might be possible for chrome as well